# How to print array element with Color

Tags: c++

I want to ask how to print array value with different color and still keep the other elements with the default color. I have a code to print color given by my professor like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

enum Type {VERTICAL = '|', HORIZONTAL = '-'};

int main()
{
        Type blue = VERTICAL;

        printf("\033[1;34m%c\033[0m\n", static_cast<char>(blue));

        Type red  = HORIZONTAL;

        printf("\033[1;31m%c\033[0m\n", static_cast<char>(red));

        return 0;
}
```

However, If I'm using printf, then my 2D array pointer will only print the character that is inputted and will give it a '\n' character, which will mess my array. Is there any way to print it beside using Windows function, (i'm using putty for compiling program). I seriously have no clue on how to do this at all. I've been searching so many web pages and none talks about this. I've finished with my programs and the final thing that I need is to display a color.

Here is what I need: 
[image]

Red color will be for the player, green will be the AI.

Comment: "However, If I'm using printf, then my 2D array pointer will only print the character that is inputted and will give it a '\n' character, which will mess my array"
How it is related with the given code?

Comment: You saying you are compiling with 'putty' makes me wonder if you are connecting to a unix-ish computer over the internet and compiling and executing there.  Putty does support the escape codes your example uses.  Perhaps you'd be interested in looking at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

Comment: There are no standards for color with consoles in C++.  You will need to consult your platform operating system API for drawing text to the console in color.  You only standard that C++ states is that the output will go to *standard* output.  That may be a console window, a terminal, or the waste bin.

Comment: Are you saying that a '\n' character is being printed when it shouldn't?

Comment: I didn't quite get your questions, what is the code that you have? Or what was the code you gave supposed to output? Because the code that you gave and what you showed you wanted to print are completely different.

Comment: My professor gave me the code above to instruct us how to print a color text on Putty. In my program, I have to somehow incorporate the code above so that my output will look the same as the picture given above. For example, The red symbol indicates it is the move by the player and the green is by the AI. I am finished writing the code to create the move for the user and the AI, but I do not how to display these moves in color so people can differentiate it. I try to use #include <Windows.h> but it gives me a fatal error though.

Comment: Your professor gave you examples of ANSI escape codes. '\033[1;31mHELLO\033[0m' for example means ESCAPE-BOLD-RED-SETCOLOR, then the HELLO text, then ESCAPE-RESET_ATTRIBUTES.  To change the color of the text you print, send the right escape sequence and text will be in that color.  When done, reset it, or change to another color